# Caliburn Micro self-replacing View/ViewModel

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a listbox to select an item for edit. I have an edit button as well. Call this the MainView[Model].

If I press the edit button the MainView[Model] shall be replaced by EditView[Model].
The EditView shall not be displayed in a area below or beside the MainView. It should be completely replaced or at least completely hide the MainView.

If edit is finished (OK, cancel) the MainView shall be displayed again.

I have tried to overlay a ContentControl but with no success.
Now, I'm thinking about a kind of NavigatorViewModel which has multiple ViewModels exposed by a property. But I'm not sure if this is the right direction to go.

Can anybody help?

Thx.

Comment: This would be just an example of view switching.  It can be entirely different view/viewmodel pairing.   You would just have to simply figure out a way to pass the index or id of the item in question to be edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would preferably use the Conductor pattern that Caliburn.Micro provides. A conductor manages one or more Screens and controls their lifetime. See [Screens, Conductors and Composition](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition) for further information.

1. At first, we need a shell. This is your "NavigatorViewModel". It is derived from `Conductor<Screen>.Collection.OneActive`, what means that it holds a list of Screens of which a single one can be active at a time:

   ```
   public interface IShell
   {
       void ActivateItem(Screen screen);
   }

   public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<Screen>.Collection.OneActive, IShell
   {
       public ShellViewModel()
       {
           this.ActivateItem(new MainViewModel());
       }
   }
   ```
2. A conductor has an `ActiveItem` property, and we want to bind a `ContentControl` to it, so we see the corresponding view:

   ```
   <!-- ShellView.xaml -->
   <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.ShellView"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

       <ContentControl Name="ActiveItem" />

   </Window>
   ```
3. Our `MainViewModel` can navigate to the `EditViewModel` using its parent, the shell:

   ```
   public class MainViewModel : Screen
   {
       public void Edit()
       {
           ((IShell)this.Parent).ActivateItem(new EditViewModel());
       }
   }
   ```
4. We bind a button to the `Edit` method:

   ```
   <!-- MainView.xaml -->
   <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainView"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

       <Button Name="Edit" Content="Edit" />

   </UserControl>
   ```
5. `EditViewModel` also derives from Screen and just contains your edit logic:

   ```
   public class EditViewModel : Screen
   {
   }
   ```
6. Finally, we bind a button to the `TryClose` method, so the view model closes itself and is removed from the shell's items. The last activated item (`MainViewModel`) will be reactivated:

   ```
   <!-- EditView.xaml -->
   <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.EditView"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

       <Button Name="TryClose" Content="Back" />

   </UserControl>
   ```

That's about it.